# Handle the result of procedure A in procedure B

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have procedure A, which has some in and out parameters. I can't change parameters or code of first procedure, but I need to get different result. I decided to create procedure B, which will pass additional parameter. I want to call procedure A from this procedure and handle result of procedure A in it. I know type of parameters, which procedure A returns.

I need somethink like this:

```
procedure A(id in number, names out names_array) is
begin
    // procedure A body
    // filling names var
end;

procedure B (id in number, myLimit in number, names out names_array) is
    temp_names names_array;
    i integer;
begin
    A(id => id, names => temp_names);
    while i < myLimit loop
        names(i) := temp_names(i);
    end loop;
end;
```

So the problem is in handling `names` (the result of procedure `A`). How I can do this correctly? Maybe with some `select ... limit myLimit` query?

Definition of names_array:

```
 TYPE names_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (40)
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `names_array`?  Is it actually a varray (very unusual)?  A nested table?  Or an associative array?

Comment: @JustinCave varray I think... but you know, after you asked me, I am not sure, I don't have code right now. Is it too neccessary?

Comment: There are differences in how you'd do the assignment depending on the collection type having to do with things like whether it's necessary to initialize the destination collection.  Is it safe to assume that the collection is dense (indexes from 1 to `count` are populated)?  Or could the collection be sparse?

Comment: @JustinCave just checked. I added definition of `names_array` in my quetion.